# Running Android service for infinite time

Tags: android, service, location

I have a location service that runs in the background and uses the location manager to send lat and long values to my server every 30 seconds. I want this service to run infinitely long until the user stops the service. But what i am observing is after few hours, the service vanishes as it reaches more than 30+ mb. I want to know how I can make it run as long as it is not stopped by the user?

Few of my observations(correct me if I am wrong):
In the allocation tracker, most of the objects that occupy the memory are the location manager objects. 
In the heap, when i cause gc, the memory allocated by my objects are vanishing and so i guess there is no memory leak. 
In the applications-->running services, i do not see any services running for 4+ hours. So What I am trying to do is not possible?

Any help/suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want it to run for an infinitely long time that's going to be difficult to test.  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why your service starts to take up more than 30 megabytes, but it is possible you are leaking memory somehow.

In the end though, your design is flawed.The best thing you can do is:

1. Use the PendingIntent method [registerLocationUpdates](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) to register for location updates. You can specify the minTime between updates here.
2. If you need send the position updates precisely every 30 seconds, you can also register a PendingIntent with the AlarmManager to have an intent get sent every 30 seconds.
3. Have this PendingIntent start an IntentService.
4. Have the IntentService send the location data to your server.
5. When the user stops your application, simply unregister your PendingIntents with the LocationManager (and potentially AlarmManager).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed information. I will do the step 1 and update you how it goes. But do you think that will keep my service running all the time?

Comment: The truth is, that your service doesn't need to run all the time. What this will do is have an IntentService spin up every 30 seconds to send to your server. Once it's done sending to your server, the service will shut down. Its the most "friendly" way to implement what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hi Justin, I used this one. public void requestLocationUpdates with LocationListener listener as last parameter. How is it different from the one that you said? I have this register in my onHandleIntent method only once (previously i was doing it every 30 seconds and i believe that could be the reason for my memory leak) and waited for my debugger to hit onLocationChanged but it never reached there. But my getlastknownlocation method gives me different lat and long values. I believe the it will have a different lat and long values only after when it hits the onLocationChanged method, right?

Comment: The one I indicated you should use is different in that a PendingIntent is used to receive your location data instead of receiving a callback via the LocationListener. getLastKnownLocation should update whenever your device receives a new location. As far as I am aware that method isn't tied to your particular location listener. If the returned location is changing, your GPS position is being updated somehow, so you know that works.

Comment: Justin, I have implemented the pendingIntent and location update works like charm. I am cancelling my pendingIntent in onDestroy method but if i forcefully stop my application, the onDestroy method is not getting called and the pendingIntent keeps alive and updating the location. Any suggestion on how to go about this issue?

Comment: This is really getting outside the scope of your question (I would suggest you ask another so others can benefit from any answers). But, as a quick idea, you could set a flag in shared preferences or in a DB when the user starts or stops your app since that is really the only time your app should be stopped. Your service can check that flag and stop the PendingIntent if need be. Please don't forget to accept the most helpful answers on your questions by clicking the checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a location service that runs in the background and uses the location manager to send lat and long values to my server every 30 seconds.

Please allow the user to choose the polling period, including "never poll".

Also, please realize that this will seriously impact the user's battery.

> I want this service to run infinitely long until the user stops the service.

This is not possible. The closest you can get is via `startForeground()`, but not even that guarantees that your service will live forever.

Moreover, this is a serious anti-pattern in Android. Users **hate** applications that try to run forever, which is why we have to contend with task killers and the like.

> But what i am observing is after few hours, the service vanishes as it reaches more than 30+ mb.

In a few hours of keeping the GPS on and the device awake all of the time, your user's battery will be dead, at which point your service and everything else vanishes.

With respect to the memory, if you think you are leaking memory, use MAT to track down the leaks.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you issue gc programatically - say every hour?

I don't know if it is impossible what you want to do. I guess it should be possible after all.
What makes me wonder is: why doesn't the VM start gc and does instead crash?

Maybe there is in fact an issue with memory leakage?

[Avoiding memory leaks](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html)-blogentry can give some hints, maybe.

Perhaps someone can give you more sophisticated advice if you give us some code of yours?

Comment: You should almost never do a manual GC collection. The GC is smart enough to perform a collection whenever it is necessary. There are only a very very small number of cases where doing a manual GC is a good idea.

Comment: I agree. But in that case, this would be a "first approach" to keep it running several hours. I guess he has some leak somewhere.

Comment: Thank you for the tips, Fildor. I tried the gc programmatically but as Justin said that does not solve the issue and i felt that the system gc was better than the manual one.